# Non-repeatitive dropdown select

Tags: javascript

I have 4 select dropdown and i want each selection to be non-repeatitive or cannot be selected twice.

Step 1 - If i select two from DROPDOWN 1,all selection number two from the other 3 dropdown should be disabled.

Step 2 - If i select one from DROPDOWN 2,all selection number one from the other 3 dropdown should be disabled AND the first selection from DROPDOWN 1 should remain disabled.

Step 3 - If i select three from DROPDOWN 3,all selection number three from the other 3 dropdown should be disabled AND the first, second selection from DROPDOWN 1 and 2 should remain disabled.

Step 4- If i select four from DROPDOWN 4,all selection number four from the other 3 dropdown should be disabled AND the first, second, third selection from DROPDOWN 1,2 and 3 should remain disabled.

But the problem is if in Step 3, the first selection is enabled wherein it suppose to be disabled.
Since i'm not really good at javascript, it gave me headache for almost 5 days figuring it out but still no luck.
Hope anyone can help me out giving simple solution in my problem.

```js
$('select').change(function() {

    $(this)
        .siblings('select')
        .children('option[value=' + this.value + ']')
        .attr('disabled', true)
        .siblings().removeAttr('disabled');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<label>DROPDOWN 1</label>
<select name="select1">
    <option>No Match</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select><br>
<label>DROPDOWN 2</label>
<select name="select2">
    <option>No Match</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select><br>
<label>DROPDOWN 3</label>
<select name="select3">
    <option>No Match</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select><br>
<label>DROPDOWN 4</label>
<select name="select4">
    <option>No Match</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('select').on('change', function() {
    selected = [];

    $('select').each(function() {

        if ($(this).val() !== "No Match")

            selected.push($(this).find('option:selected').val());

    });
    console.log(selected);

    $('select').children().each(function(index) {

        if ($.inArray($(this).val(), selected) !== -1) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true);

        } else {
            $(this).attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>DROPDOWN 1</label>
<select name="select1">
    <option>No Match</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select><br>
<label>DROPDOWN 2</label>
<select name="select2">
    <option>No Match</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select><br>
<label>DROPDOWN 3</label>
<select name="select3">
    <option>No Match</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select><br>
<label>DROPDOWN 4</label>
<select name="select4">
    <option>No Match</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
```

Here is idea -> on each dropdown change, itterate through all dropdowns, including current, and (re)create array of selected options, then iterate through every children (options), and set attribute accordingly.

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    selected = [];

    $('select').each(function() {

        if ($(this).val() !== "No Match")

            selected.push($(this).find('option:selected').val());

    });
    console.log(selected);

    $('select').children().each(function(index) {

        if ($.inArray($(this).val(), selected) !== -1) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true);

        } else {
            $(this).attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/g3t3v22o/

P.S. Array re-creation is needed, in case that user changes his mind (while he can do it, while there are some options left). Check console.log, to see how selected array is changed, during process...

Comment: Sir thank you for sharing your ingenuity.Its perfect and you provide the exact flow that we've wanted.

Comment: @josephlumongtad, thank you, glad to help! It was interesting question. :)