# 2 identical select list, but don't allow the same values selected in them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here i have the javascript code for my task: https://jsfiddle.net/gckkvLcv/4/

```
<select id="s1">
  <option selected="selected">USD</option>
  <option>KZT</option>
  <option>EUR</option>
</select>
<select id="s2">
  <option>USD</option>
  <option selected="selected">KZT</option>
  <option>EUR</option>
</select>
```

1. I need to translate it to a jQuery version.
2. On a document load i can see the same values in a select lists. I need to disable that behavior.

Comment: There was similar question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40807815/non-repeatitive-dropdown-select/40809544#40809544 Hope it will help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery that could be done simply like :

```
$('.tracked_select').on('change', function() {
    //Get selected options
    var selected_options = $('.tracked_select').map(function(){
      return this.value
    }).get();

    //Disable the already selected options and enable others
    $('.tracked_select option').each(function(index) {
      $(this).prop('disabled', $.inArray($(this).val(), selected_options) != -1);
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
trigger_chane();

$('.tracked_select').on('change', function() {
  trigger_chane();
});

function trigger_chane(){
  var selected_options = $('.tracked_select').map(function(){
    return this.value
  }).get();

  $('.tracked_select option').each(function(index) {
    $(this).prop('disabled', $.inArray($(this).val(), selected_options) != -1);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="tracked_select">
  <option selected="selected">USD</option>
  <option>KZT</option>
  <option>EUR</option>
</select>
<select class="tracked_select">
  <option>USD</option>
  <option selected="selected">KZT</option>
  <option>EUR</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @AlexanderKim is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: It's almost what i want, you're just adding disabled attribute on the option? Could you show how to make USD on second select disabled at the page load? Also i want this functionality on both selects, so user won't exchange the same currency, hope you understand.

Comment: I think i got you, you could simply call the function on load, check my update.